# fetch data from given wikipedia url

Tags: iphone, xcode

all

I have this link http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content  and I want to fetch from this url. (get the data from ) through anyxml rule.. when ever I run this code it can fetch any data

```
NSString *someXML = @"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&  titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content";

TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someXML]] retain];

records = [NSMutableArray array];

[records retain];

if (tbxml.rootXMLElement)

[self traverseElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement];

[tbxml release];
```

any tutorial . .you have. .then plz give it to me

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what errors you have received.

Comment: I have convert that link to xml formate. but not find any solution, here is the link http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content&format=xml

Comment: tbxml.rootXMLElement is returning null. any solution ..

Comment: @sosborn I want to fetch the data from this xml link http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content&format=xml.. simple

Answer (score 0):

I think your url is incorrect. It is return HTML, not XML. Try to specify the format you need in the url by adding a format parameter.

```
NSString *someXML = @"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&  titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content&format=xml
```

Comment: I have alerady shown in my comment and I upddate the link thorugh the link.. but the problem is that It can fetch the data . .

Comment: type NSLog(@"%@", tbxml) after you get the data. Does it show what it should show?